# Как преобразовать ключи объекта вида «key[index]» к массиву?

Tags: javascript

Господа, как кошерно преобразовать это

```
{
  list: {
    "action_buttons[0]": "View",
    "action_buttons[1]": "Share",
    "action_buttons[2]": "Download",
    "columns[0]": "Date of Study",
    "columns[1]": "Patient",
    "columns[2]": "File name",
    "columns[3]": "Reporting <br>Physician",
    "columns[4]": "Institution"
  }
}
```

в

```
{
  list: {
    "action_buttons": [
      "View", "Share", "Download"
    ],
    "columns": [
      "Date of Study", "Patient", "File name", "Reporting <br>Physician", "Institution" 
    ]
  }
}
```

Может в lodash какой-то метод есть? Найти не могу.

Comment: напишите регулярное выражение на ключ и в цикле пуште соответствующие значения в соответствующий массив

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для преобразования нужно пройтись по всем ключам объекта, разобрать имя свойства определив имя свойства в результирующем объекте и место в которое положить значение.

Для обхода можно воспользоваться методами [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), который возвращает список пар ключ/значение, и [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), который соберет обработанные пары в новый объект.

```
obj.list = Object.entries(obj.list).reduce((acc,cur)=> ... , {});
```

Разобрать имя свойства вида: `propertyName[index]` можно с помощью регулярного выражения, например такого: `/(.+)\[(\d+)\]/`, которое сразу выдаст и имя свойства и индекс.

Далее надо будет просто установить нужное значение в объекте аккумуляторе.

Пример в сборе:

```js
var obj = {
  list: {
    "action_buttons[0]": "View",
    "action_buttons[1]": "Share",
    "action_buttons[2]": "Download",
    "columns[0]": "Date of Study",
    "columns[1]": "Patient",
    "columns[2]": "File name",
    "columns[3]": "Reporting <br>Physician",
    "columns[4]": "Institution"
  }
};

obj.list = Object.entries(obj.list).reduce((acc, cur) => {
  var [, keyName, num] = cur[0].match(/(.+)\[(\d+)\]/);
  if (!acc[keyName]) acc[keyName] = [];
  acc[keyName][num] = cur[1];
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(obj.list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот такое решение в итоге вышло:

```js
const translations = {
  prop: "string",
  arr: {},
  obj: {
    nested: {
      sub_nested: {
        "buttons[0]": "View",
        "buttons[1]": "Share",
        "buttons[2]": "Download",
        "prop[0]": "Date of Study",
        "prop[1]": "Patient",
        "prop[2]": "File name",
        "prop[3]": "Reporting <br>Physician",
        "prop[4]": "Institution"
      }
    }
  },
  list: {
    "buttons[0]": "View",
    "buttons[1]": "Share",
    "buttons[2]": "Download",
    "columns[0]": "Date of Study",
    "columns[1]": "Patient",
    "columns[2]": "File name",
    "columns[3]": "Reporting <br>Physician",
    "columns[4]": "Institution",
    "norm": "value"
  }
};

console.clear()

const isObject = obj => obj instanceof Object && !Array.isArray(obj)

function stableObject (obj) {
  const re = /^(.*?)\[(\d+)\]$/
  const result = {}
  for (const prop of Object.keys(obj)) {
    const match = prop.match(re)
    if (match) {
      if (typeof result[match[1]] === "undefined") {
        result[match[1]] = []
      }
      result[match[1]][match[2]] = obj[prop]
    } else if (isObject(obj[prop])) {
      result[prop] = stableObject(obj[prop])
    } else {
      result[prop] = obj[prop]
    }
  }
  return result
}

for (const key in translations) {
  if (isObject(translations[key])) {
    translations[key] = stableObject(translations[key])
  }
}

document.getElementById('textarea').value = JSON.stringify((translations), null, 2)
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea" rows="50" cols="90"></textarea>
```